# php mysql select query returns true but cant select row i inserted myself for testing

Tags: php, mysql

I used a simple select to select where the row whose email address is equal to the address recieved by post, but everytime i use num rows to check if it returned a row it returns a 0 and moves on the else statement, the manually entered the a row the connections table to  test the query, any help please i been checking lines for couple of hours, would help to get a fresh pair of eyes, maybe iv been looking at the screen for too long i cant tell the difference, so taking a breather from the desk

Heres my table structure just in case i got something wrong here

[DATA TABLE STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE4je.jpg)

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'connect_database';

session_start();

$supplier_name = $_SESSION['supplier_name'];
$supplier_email = $_SESSION['supplier_email'];
$supplier_id = $_SESSION['supplier_id'];

if(isset($_POST['client_email'])) {        
  $input = $_POST['client_email'];        
  $client_email_to_add = trim($input," ");    

  $add_client_query = "SELECT * FROM `connections` WHERE `client` = '$client_email_to_add'";
  $add_client_query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$add_client_query);

  if($add_client_query_run !== false){
        $num_rows =mysqli_num_rows($add_client_query_run);
        if($num_rows == 1) {
          header("location:dashboard_clients.php?response=".urlencode(" $client_email_to_add Client found")."&type=".urlencode(1));
        } else {
          header("location:dashboard_clients.php?response=".urlencode("$client_email_to_add Client was not found")."&type=".urlencode(0));
        }
  } else {
    echo "Query did not run";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you try echoing `$client_email_to_add` before running the query?

Comment: let me try that right now

Comment: Use count in query like:  
$add_client_query = "SELECT count(*) FROM `connections` WHERE `client` = '$client_email_to_add'"; 
and compare response of query directly instead.

Comment: `$add_client_query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$add_client_query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
if(mysqli_num_rows($add_client_query_run) >= 1) {
  header("location:dashboard_clients.php?response=".urlencode(" $client_email_to_add Client found")."&type=".urlencode(1));
} else {
  header("location:dashboard_clients.php?response=".urlencode("$client_email_to_add Client was not found")."&type=".urlencode(0));
}`

Comment: also `$add_client_query = "SELECT * FROM `connections` WHERE `client` = $client_email_to_add";`

Answer (score 0):

Write your code as below:-

```
// include file by below way
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/connect_database');
//$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
session_start();

$supplier_name = $_SESSION['supplier_name'];
$supplier_email = $_SESSION['supplier_email'];
$supplier_id = $_SESSION['supplier_id'];


  if(isset($_POST['client_email'])){

      $input = $_POST['client_email'];

      $client_email_to_add = trim($input," ");    

      $add_client_query = "SELECT * FROM `connections` WHERE `client` = '$client_email_to_add'";

      $add_client_query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$add_client_query);

     // $add_client_query_run will returns True or False
     if($add_client_query_run){     
        // success
        header("location:dashboard_clients.php?response=".urlencode(" $client_email_to_add Client found")."&type=".urlencode(1));
        exit; // write exit after header to stop executuon of below code
     }
    else{
       // check query errors. assume your connection object is $conn
       printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
       //  echo "Query did not run";
        header("location:dashboard_clients.php?response=".urlencode("$client_email_to_add Client was not found")."&type=".urlencode(0));
        exit; // write exit after header to stop executuon of below code
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you :)